# How can I extract only the pid column and only the pathname column in the lsof output?

Tags: text-processing, awk, python, perl, lsof

```
$ sudo lsof -u t  |   grep -i "\.pdf" 

evince  1788    t   37r      REG                8,4    176328     134478 /home/t/some/path1/white space/string1 + string2 string3.pdf
evince  3737    t   36r      REG                8,4   1252636    6692680 /home/t/some/path2/white space/string5 string3.pdf
```

How can I extract only the second column (pids of processes)?

How can I extract only the ninth column (pathnames of files)? (pathnames can contain any character allowed by Linux and ext4 file systems)

My real command is

```
$ sudo lsof -u t  | grep -v "wineserv" | grep REG  |   grep "\.pdf" | grep  "string"
```

where I would search for records whose first column "COMMAND" isn't `wineserv`, and fifth column "TYPE" is `REG`, and whose ninth column "NAME" contains `.pdf` and `string`.

Prefer bash, awk or Python solutions (and maybe Perl, but I don't know Perl, so won't be able to verify if it is correct or modify it later)

Thanks.

Comment: `lsof` has `-F` flag according to the manual, so you could do `lsof -F p` to get just the PID itself. Let me know if you want that as an answer, but of course I can do Python and awk  parsing as well

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks, and yes. See my update.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299040/117549

Comment: no need for lsof: `find /proc/*/fd -ilname '*.pdf' 2>/dev/null | awk -F/ '{print$3}'` (btw, this will also work if the filenames contain newline, spaces, etc).

Comment: @mosvy Thanks. How is using parsing output of find on /proc file system compared to parsing lsof output?

Comment: @mosvy Besides only needing pid, I also want only pathname of pdf file. Can you modify `find /proc/*/fd -ilname '*.pdf' 2>/dev/null | awk -F/ '{print$3}'` accordingly?

Comment: `find /proc/*/fd -ilname '*.pdf' -printf '%l\n'` , `find /proc/*/fd -ilname '*.pdf' -printf '%p\t%l\n'`. You can also get that info with whatever language you want (`C`, `perl`, `python`, etc). The value added by a tool like `lsof` should be the ease of use and the human-friendly way it presents that info -- and `lsof` fails at both spectacularly.

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions:

```
$ ... | perl -nlE '/.*? (\d+).*?(\/.*)/ and print("$1 ; $2")' 

1788 ; /home/t/some/path1/white space/string1 + string2 string3.pdf
3737 ; /home/t/some/path2/white space/string5 string3.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks. By `(\/.*)`, do you assume that lsof always output resolved absolute pathnames not relative pathnames? see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501002/does-lsof-always-show-the-resolved-absolute-pathnames-of-opened-files

Comment: @Tim, yes (i though this is the default behavior of lsof). I believe some other situations can also easily be covered (some limitations are predictable)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements this should work:

```
awk '{ for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i ~ "string" && $1 != "wineserv" && $5 == "REG" && $NF ~ "\.pdf$") {
        $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""
        print
    }
}}'
```

- Loop through all the fields from 9 to the end, if one contains `string`:

  - Check that field 1 does not equal `wineserv`
  - field 5 does equal `REG`
  - The last field contains `.pdf` (I think it's safe to assume that even if the file has whitespace the extension should be in the last part)
- If all conditions are met erase the first 8 fields and print what's left

Comment: Thanks.`$NF ~ ".pdf"` the `.` doesn't work as a literal dot.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks didn't realize that.  I'll update with ```\```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say `$NF ~ "\.pdf"` doesn't work either. pathnames containing `/.../pdf.../...` will still match. I don't know why they match.

Comment: @Tim: How about `"\.pdf$"`

Comment: That works. But still why `/.../pdf.../...` matches `\.pdf`?

Comment: Why does `PDFXCview  4333    t  255r      REG                8,4       880   27793700 /home/t/program_files/document/formats/pdf/TrackerSoftware/pdfxcview/pdfxchange_portable/PDFXCview` match `\.pdf`?

Comment: @Tim: It doesn't for me using mawk 1.2

Comment: I am using GNU Awk 4.1.4. (1) Does gawk cause the problem?  (2) What do you think of gawk vs mawk?

Comment: Thanks. If I would like to allow arbitrary number of `string`'s to match against, and I would like to put the awk command in to a bash script which accept the `string`'s as command line arguments, how would you arrange the arbitrary number of `string`'s (provided as positional parameters in the shell script) in the the awk command in the shell script? (the relation between multiple `string`'s is AND, i.e. all the `string`'s must appear in the pathname, albeit in arbitrary order.

Comment: Thanks. The output has a pathname in each line. In each line, there are several blank spaces(?) in front of a pathname. Can the blank spaces be suppressed in the output?

Comment: Perhaps: `$NF ~  /\.pdf/ `